Linearly independent rows of a matrix under orthogonal transformations.
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{9\times 6}$ be a full-column rank matrix, with $I=\{i_1,\dots,i_6\}$ being a set of indeces of linearly independent rows of $A$. Define two orthogonal matrices $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{9\times 9}$, $R\in\mathbb{R}^{6\times 6}$. Then $Q^{-1}=Q^T$, $R^{-1}=R^T$. Consider the matrix $B=Q\,A\,R^T$. Clearly, $B$ is also full-column rank. Can we conclude that the rows of $B$ with indeces in $I$ are also linearly independent?
This is my attempt:
Intuitively, there must be a permutation matrix $P$, which swaps all the linearly independent rows of $A$ from $1$ to $6$, namely $A'=PA$.  Applying SVD decomposition to $A'$ in partinioned form yields:
$A'=[U_1\,U_2]\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma & 0\\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V_1^T \\ V_2^T \end{bmatrix}$. Then: $A=P^T\,U_1\Sigma\, V_1^T$. By substituting in $B$, one has:
$B=(QP^T\,U_1)\Sigma\, (V_1^TR^T)$
I am stuck here, though.
